# Definite integral on a bivariate normal

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate this function:

$$a\int_{x=-R}^{x=+R}\int_{y=-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{y=+\sqrt{R^2-x^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left( \left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{c}\right)^2\right)\right)\,dx \,dy$$

However, Wolfram Alpha tells me that there is no analytical expression.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We don't know what you're doing wrong if you've not given any context for your integral or your attempts at it.

Comment: But there are many functions that cannot be integrable (e.g. $\exp(-x^2)$).

Comment: That is a strange way to set up your limits...why would you stick $x$ in your integration limits _after_ you have integrated over $x$? Is your domain a circle of radius $R$? If so, I would put the $dy$ integral on the inside.

Comment: @bames You are right. Corrected.